# Weird signature constraining behavior of alloy5 (git commit 30b41ae8125f69657)

Tags: alloy

Can somebody clarify what is going wrong here:

```
enum Stage { Receive, Check, Drop, Save, Forward, Delivered }

sig StartStage in Receive {}
-- { StartStage = Receive } -- do not constrain StartStage???
-- if uncommented here, but commented in fact below, then StartStage may be empty
-- Why? Is it a bug?

sig FinalStage in Drop + Delivered {}

fact {
  StartStage = Receive
  FinalStage = Drop + Delivered
}
```

In this code StartStage can be constrained only via separate **fact** section. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, why someone votes down, as my question may be useful for newbies.

Answer is simple, in constraint's section after signature's fields section, there is an implicit quantification:

enum E {A, B, C}

sig S {} {S = A + B}
 is actually 
sig S {} { all this : S |  S = A + B }
which satisfied by two values of S: empty set {} and A + B set.

It is mentioned in docs (implicit quantification), but in some cases AlloyTools behaviour may look somewhat unexpectedly for beginner (me, for instance).